# Determine how many times a substring occurs adjacently in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, substring

I want to calculate how many times a substring occurs "adjacently" in a string, 
for example, given the string "8448442844" and the substring "844", I want the result "2".
I know the string.count(substring) function, in this example, using this function, I will get the result "3". But I want the result "2". How can I achieve my goal, thanks in advance.

Comment: Write a algorithm for this, simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work just fine for any adjacent sub string:

```
a = "8448442844"
sol, sub = 0, "844"

for i in range(1, a.count(sub)+1):
  if a.count(str(sub*i)): sol = i
  else: break
print (sol)
# 2
```

Can also convert to a one-liner using `Comprehension` and `sum`:

```
a, sub = "8448442844", "844"
sol = sum([1 for x in range(1, a.count(sub)+1) if a.count(str(sub*x))])
# 2
```

Comment: Thank you! I selected your answer as best answer : )

Answer (score 0):

Use str.count

```
>>> nStr = '000123000123'

>>> nStr.count('123')

2
```

Or use something like this

```
nStr = '000123000123'
pattern = '123'
count =0
flag=True
start=0
while flag:
    a = nStr.find(pattern,start)  # find() returns -1 if the word is not found, 
                                  #start i the starting index from the search starts(default value is 0)
    if a==-1:          #if pattern not found set flag to False
        flag=False
    else:               # if word is found increase count and set starting index to a+1
        count+=1        
        start=a+1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try it like this. Maybe put it in a def. It works just fine

```
import string

s = "8448442844"
sub = "844"
max_sub = sub
count = 0

while string.find(s, max_sub) != -1:
    max_sub = max_sub + sub
    count +=1

print count
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trick with [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split), [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.groupby) and [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max) to get the result:

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: "8448442844".split("844")
Out[2]: ['', '', '2', '']

In [3]: [len(list(lst)) for key, lst in itertools.groupby("8448442844".split("844")) if key == ""]
Out[3]: [2, 1]

In [4]: max([len(list(lst)) for key, lst in itertools.groupby("8448442844".split("844")) if key == ""])
Out[4]: 2
```